# Android - get styleable value by name

Tags: android, declare-styleable

Is there a way to get styleable by name, for example if I have string "Text" is it possible to get `R.styleable.CustomView_Text` value (by value I mean just index in `R.styleable.CustomView` array, not attribute value) without reflection?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="CustomView">

        <attr name="Text" format="string" />

    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Resources.getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method, setting the `defType` param as 'styleable'.